# Which software package to install using 12.04 server as a Openvpn server

Tags: 12.04, openvpn

When I get to the "Install Software Packages" while installing the server which software packages do I need to run the Openvpn server.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `openvpn` package looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

The package you may want to install is named `openvpn`, to install press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

For more information see [Official Ubuntu server guide for configuring OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openvpn.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok need to clarify what I was asking. I know I need to install Openvpn, what I am asking is when I am installing the server and get to the screen "Install Software Package" which starts with SSH server I was wondering do I need to install any of these or just install basic server and then OpenVpn.